# Won't display IP address in CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, ip-address

I am trying to retrieve the running applications, the computers' username and its IP address. Now, every time that the results are saved on the text file, the IP address part would always give me this result:

```
"Length"
"11"
```

Is there any way to get the IP address?

```
$savepath = "C:\Users\$([Environment]::UserName)\Desktop\apps\runningapps.txt"

Get-Process | where {$_.mainwindowtitle.length -ne 0} |
    select name, mainwindowtitle| ConvertTo-Csv -NoType |
    Set-Content $savepath
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Add-Content $savepath
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress } | 
    Select -Expand IPAddress |
    Where { $_ -notlike "*:*" } | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Add-Content $savepath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP addresses are a list of strings, so you can write them directly to the output file if you want them one address per line:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress } | 
    Select -Expand IPAddress |
    Where { $_ -notlike "*:*" } | Add-Content $savepath
```

If you want the addresses as a comma separated list in one line you need to join them first:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress } | 
    Select -Expand IPAddress |
    Where { $_ -notlike "*:*" }) -join ',' | Add-Content $savepath
```

`ConvertTo-Csv` won't help you here, because it takes an object as input and outputs a comma-separated list of the object's properties. If your input objects are strings (which have only the property `Length`) then the output becomes a list of the lengths of the input strings.

---

As a side note: a simpler way of building the output file path is to use the `USERPROFILE` environment variable:

```
$savepath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\apps\runningapps.txt"
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply sir! This works! Thank you